# Visual C++ and REST API

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rest

I've been searching around the net trying to find a basic outline of how to use any type of REST API libraries with Visual C++ 2019.  I"m brand new to programming in C++ and am interested in playing around with an app to report status of my Hue Lights.

Links from Microsoft are tedious at best and not entirely helpful.  So, does anyone have a good primer on C++ and how to use a REST API with Visual Studio 2019 with C++?

Comment: At CppCon 2018 there was a library called ‘Feather’ which looked really interesting. It’s a web framework. I had wanted to play around with it but was side tracked by another project

Answer (score 1):

The [C++ REST SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/), might be of some interest to you. This originally shipped as part of the Visual C++ product, but was released as open source many years ago. I haven't played with it recently, the repo (linked above), does include a number of sample applications that can get you started.

[C++ REST SDK Getting Tarted Tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial)

Sincerely,
Ed Dore